# how to constraint something to the center top anchor

Tags: swift, constraints, anchor, center, nslayoutconstraint

In my code below I am trying to constraint something to the top of the center point of the uiscreen. I have added a image of what I am looking for below. The code below is what I tried it pins it the center of the screen and has the object in the middle of the screen.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var box = UIImageView()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        box.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(box)
        box.backgroundColor = .systemPink
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([

            box.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.heightAnchor, multiplier : 0.25),
            box.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor, multiplier : 0.25),
            box.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor ),
            box.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor),


        ])
    }


}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove `centerYAnchor` constraint no your `box` and set `bottomAnchor` instead.

Remove: `box.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor)`

Add: `box.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor)`

Correct constraints:

```
NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
    box.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.heightAnchor, multiplier: 0.25),
    box.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor, multiplier: 0.25),
    box.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor),
    box.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor)
])
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Remove this:

`box.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor )`

Add this:

`box.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor, constant: 20) //Add padding accordingly`

Answer (score 0):

Add below solution as it is...it will help you to run perfectly...!!!

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        box.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(box)
        box.backgroundColor = .systemPink
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([

            box.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.heightAnchor, multiplier : 0.25),
            box.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor, multiplier : 0.25),
            box.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor, constant: 16),
            box.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor )
            ])
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
```

Note :- You're adding `box.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor)` this constraint, due to which you are unable to center postion your box.